# Openrasta posting to resource at the base uri

Tags: openrasta

I have a site in iis7 hosting several openrasta applications as virtual directories. One of these openrasta application hosts a single resource, so I want it to run in the root of that virtual directory. I am able to GET the resource succesfully but am unable to POST the resource. When POSTing I get a 405 error.

Locally it looks like:

```
http://localhost/OpenRastaApp1/Resource1
http://localhost/OpenRastaApp1/Resource2
http://localhost/OpenRastaApp2/Resource3
http://localhost/OpenRastaApp2/Resource4
```

I want to add another app, but as this app will only contain 1 resource I want to access it through the base uri of the app. I.e.

```
http://localhost/OpenRastaApp3 not http://localhost/OpenRastaApp3/Resource5
```

I am able to GET resource5 but am unable to POST to it using the below configuration.

It should not match the template "/{id}" as I do not include an ID when posting.

My configuration is as follows:

```
ResourceSpace.Has
    .ResourcesOfType<ThingResource>()
    .AtUri("/").And
    .AtUri("/{id}")
    .HandledBy<ThingHandler>()
    .AsJsonDataContract();
```

And my handler code is:

```
public class ThingHandler
{
    [HttpOperation(HttpMethod.POST)]
    public OperationResult Post(ThingResource thingResource)
    {
        var thing = thingResource.ToThingEntity();
        thing = _thingService.Make(thing);
        return new OperationResult.OK(thing.ToThingResource());
    }

    [HttpOperation(HttpMethod.GET)]
    public OperationResult Get(int id)
    {
        var thing = _thingService.Get(id);
        return new OperationResult.OK(thing.ToThingResource());
    }
}
```

Debug log as follows

```
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Verbose(0) Incoming host request for http://api.local.site.com/Thing
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Verbose(0) Adding communication context data
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Warning(0) Contributor call for BootstrapperContributor had a null Action.
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor ExceptionHandlerContributor.LogException
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor HttpMethodOverriderContributor.OverrideHttpVerb
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor DigestAuthorizerContributor.ReadCredentials
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor UriDecoratorsContributor.ProcessDecorators
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor ResourceTypeResolverContributor.ResolveResource
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor HandlerResolverContributor.ResolveHandler
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor OperationCreatorContributor.CreateOperations
    13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Verbose(0) Created operation named Post with signature ThingHandler::Post(ThingResource ThingResource)
    13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Verbose(0) Created operation named Get with signature ThingHandler::Get(Int32 id)
    13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Verbose(0) Created operation named Amend with signature ThingHandler::Amend(ThingResource ThingResource)
    13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Verbose(0) Created operation named Cancel with signature ThingHandler::Cancel(Int32 id)
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor OperationFilterContributor.ProcessOperations
    13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Verbose(0) Found 1 operation(s) with a matching name.
    13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Verbose(0) Found 1 operation(s) with matching [HttpOperation] attribute.
    13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Verbose(0) No resource or no uri name. Not filtering.
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in OpenRasta.DLL
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in OpenRasta.DLL
    13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Error(0) None of the operations had members that could be matches against the uri parameters:
id=Thing;

13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Verbose(0) Pipeline is in RenderNow mode.
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor OperationResultInvokerContributor.RunOperationResult
    13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Information(0) Executing OperationResult OperationResult: type=MethodNotAllowed, statusCode=405.
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor ResponseEntityCodecResolverContributor.FindResponseCodec
    13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Information(0) No response codec was searched for. The response entity is null or a response codec is already set.
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor DigestAuthorizerContributor.WriteCredentialRequest
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor ResponseEntityWriterContributor.WriteResponse
    13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Verbose(0) There was no response entity, not rendering.
    13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Verbose(0) Writing http headers.
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
13-[2011-03-01 10:38:59Z] Information(0) Pipeline finished.
```

Anyone out there able to help me with this?

Cheers

Dave

Comment: If you could add a debug log that'd let us know what actually happens when POSTing.

Answer (score 0):

Without log, I'd only provide one simple potential answer. Check what other modules you have defined in IIS and remove (or reorder) the ones that would take a POST to / (such as default documents). A lot of those modules will greedily assume they own the request, causing compat hell.

Comment: I've reordered the modules so that the OpenRastaModule is first and it is still not working. What log would you need to see?

Comment: Attach the debugger (or DebugView) to the iis worker process and do your request on the uri, that'll give you a log. I've heard about this issue yesterday at dinner actually, so really interested to get down to it. Note that modules defined for the server (default documents) are executed before the ones in your app by default.

Comment: Sorry for the delay getting back to you. I've amended the original question with the output from the debugger. I checked the server modules but may have missed something, I'll recheck them now.

Answer (score 0):

Posting another answer as the problem is different.

The log says you attempt to do something on /Thing, which matches the template /{id}. That template is then mapped in your method to an id of type int. Thing cannot be converted to int, hence the failure.

Are you saying that your application is in a virtual directory in /Thing? If that's the case, either you need to mark the virtual directory as an application, or you need to map the URI as /Thing/{id} and /Thing/ instead.

Comment: I have amended the original post with more detail on my setup. Does this make it any clearer? Thanks again.

Comment: Well, no not really. The log says:  None of the operations had members that could be matches against the uri parameters id=Thing; That means OpenRasta sees the URI you post to (obviously somethingsomething/Thing, which was in your previous debug log and is not there anymore, even though the debug log still sees it, so I assume you just edited the log manually), matches it against the uri template to find the resource (aka /{id} because you POSTed to /Thing and not to /). Have you checked in IIS that your virtual directory *is* an application? See my comment above as to why.